# Use existing sqlite database in cordova

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Hello I'm creating a application with ionic framework and cordova and want to use a sqlite database to store the data.

So how can I use a existing sqlite database for this purpose? 
Where do I have to save the database so that cordova can find it and uses it if I compile for a platform?

### Edit:

I get the following error if I try to open the db in the recommend way:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase')
openDB (ng-cordova.min.js, line 9)
(anonyme Funktion) (app.js, line 19)
(anonyme Funktion) (ionic.bundle.js, line 44243)
onPlatformReady (ionic.bundle.js, line 2396)
onWindowLoad (ionic.bundle.js, line 2375)
```

Here is the head section of my index.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


<!-- cordova sqlite extenseion -->
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>


<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
//Database variable
var db = null;

angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "db.spareParts" });

    var query = "SELECT cars.name FROM cars";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
        if(res.rows.length > 0) {
            console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(0).name);
        } else {
            console.log("No results found");
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });


  });
})
```

The database db.spareParts is stored in the root www directory and is a sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*So how can I use a existing sqlite database for this purpose?*
You can use the existing sqlite database by using the built-in WebSQL. You **do not** need to install any plugin. Please see the link [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) for more details.
Note that there is limitation to the amount of storage using the standard approach.(I think it is about 5MB).
If you want to store more than the allowed standard storage than you need to use the sqlite plugin. Link [here](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) for details.

*Where do I have to save the database so that cordova can find it and uses it if I compile for a platform?*
You do not need to specify the location path for storing the database. The database open function call will automatically **creates and stores** it in a convenient location.

**Edit 1:**

What I understand from your edited question is that you require a **pre-populated** sqlite3 db to be used for your application.
Copying your db to the www directory will **not** work. You need to **copy** the pre-populated db to the default location where the app will use it for your application. The location is different for different platforms (iOS, Android, Windows). Also within a platform the location path for the db storage is different. E.g for Android Jelly bean the location path is different to the one in Android KitKat. Hence as far as I know you will not a find a complete solution on the Web for copying the db to the default location of the app.
This is a completely a different proposition.
You need to search stackoverflow for **pre populated sqlite with cordova** to get useful answers.
What I have answered is to create a new db in your application from scratch.
Also relating to your error.
You need to check that the **deviceready** event is fired before calling any **cordova/phonegap** related code.

Comment: hi frank I just edited my posting. I tried the way the with sqlite plugin but I get a error.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice with pre populated sqlite with cordova. I will take a look on it. But my main problem now is that I do get this error. I am creating the db now in the .ready function like in this example:

https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Well it turns out that I have to store the database name in a variable and then call $cordovaSQLite.openDB(dbName) on it to bring it to work. But its only working in the iOS emulator not in the browser.

Comment: I don't think **Desktop** browser supports SQlite plugins. You will need to use local storage or IndexDB if you want it to work in the desktop browser as well.

Comment: @frank, do you mean [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB), rather than IndexDB?

Answer (score 6):

i fixed this problem after a very long suffering :)

the prepopulated database MUST be in the "dataDirectory" of your application

at first you need to check if the db file exists in that directory, if not, you must copy it from application directory (i.e. /www folder)

check this piece of code

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    src = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'data.sqlite';

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(src, function () {
        db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('data.sqlite');
    }, function () {
        $scope.copyDb('data.sqlite');
    });

    $scope.copyDb = function (dbName) {

        var sourceFileName = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/' + dbName;
        var targetDirName = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

        return Promise.all([
            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolveLocalFileSystemURL(sourceFileName, resolve, reject);
            }),
            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolveLocalFileSystemURL(targetDirName, resolve, reject);
            })
        ]).then(function (files) {
            var sourceFile = files[0];
            var targetDir = files[1];
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                targetDir.getFile(dbName, {}, resolve, reject);
            }).then(function () {
                console.log("file already copied");
            }).catch(function () {
                console.log("file doesn't exist, copying it");
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    sourceFile.copyTo(targetDir, dbName, resolve, reject);
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log("database file copied");
                    db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('data.sqlite');
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

check this link

[prepopulated db demo](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-prepopulated-database-demo)

Comment: With minor modifications, I was able to use your code in my project too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(window.cordova) {
      // App syntax
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("myapp.db");
    } else {
      // Ionic serve syntax
      db = window.openDatabase("myapp.db", "1.0", "My app", -1);
    }
```

Comment: Kindly add some supporting information. It would be helpful to the OP as well as other who seek the answer