# ngCordova doesn't work with sqlite Plugin in a browser

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, debugging, console

I am building my cordova APP. After creating a blank project, I install ngCordova with bower and then install ngCordova. I add ngCordova script in my index.html (after ionic.bundle.js and before cordova.js). I then install a sqlite plugin. And this is where the bug comes in.

I **CANNOT** debug by **Web Inspector** from my Safari browser because my ngCordova doesn't work well with sqlite plugin in a browser. I am using cordova-sqlite-storage 0.7.15-dev "Cordova sqlite storage plugin" plugin but my web inspector continuously complains "**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase')**"

I did some research about ngCordova and found this http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/. According to doc, I should develop on my real device instead of a browser because some plugins don't work in the emulator, such as the Camera plugin. But I only need use sqlite plugin which should be supported by browser.

Does anyone know how to make ngCordova work well with sqlite plugin in a browser?

Cordova version: 5.4.1
Iphone 5c: iOS 9.1
Mac: 10.10.5
Xcode:7.1.1

My controller.js file is attached.

```
var db = null;

angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            }
            if(window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db");
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");
        });
})

.controller('SqliteCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

    $scope.insert = function(firstname, lastname) {
        alert("test");
        var query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [firstname, lastname]).then(function(res) {
            alert("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
        }, function (err) {
            alert(err);
        });
    }

    $scope.select = function(lastname) {
        var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people WHERE lastname = ?";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [lastname]).then(function(res) {
            if(res.rows.length > 0) {
                console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(0).firstname + " " + res.rows.item(0).lastname);
            } else {
                console.log("No results found");
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: You should paste your `controller.js` code here. We would need to see the code, not an image. You can use the [edit] link to update your answer.

Comment: To which line points your error?

Comment: There is already a bunch of relating SO questions relating your issue...for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400047/errors-using-the-ngcordova-cordovasqlite-plugin-with-ionic) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669396/use-existing-sqlite-database-in-cordova)

Comment: thanks. 
if (window.cordova && window.SQLitePlugin) { var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB( 'accounts.db', 1 ); } else { db = window.openDatabase('accounts', '1.0', 'accounts.db', 100 * 1024 * 1024); } fix my error

Answer (score 0):

My advice is for you to do without SQLite plugin in as much as SQLite can work without using a plugin on Cordova.